# Why does `ldd` resolve `libc.so` to `ld.so`?

Tags: glibc, loading

On my machine, `ldd` is showing `libc.so.6` resolve to `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

```
ldd binary
  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x564329071000)
  libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x564329071000)
  libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x7f7b1e631000)
  libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x564329071000)
```

I thought `ldd`'s resolution was purely name-based, so it would roughly search for `libc.so.6` (potentially with minor versions) in the `ld` search path.  But I'm seeing it resolve to the `ld` library, which is a completely different name.

On another machine, it behaves as expected:

```
ldd binary
  linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd467d4000)
  libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffb22055000)
  libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ffb21e3b000)
  libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffb21a70000)
  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055a9661b0000)
```

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Can you elaborate?  The unexpected output (the former) is the non-Debian system.

Comment: I got the same (unexpected) output in an alpine linux docker container.